# How do you detach an object within a parent object in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a unit test for testing that inserting the same object in the database twice will give an `ArgumentException`. I have this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

And this unit test:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task AddFooAsync_ContainsExistingFoo_TrowsArgumentException()
    {
        // arrange
        using var context = new MyDbContext(MockDbContext.CreateInMemoryContext());
        var fooRepository = new FooRepository(context, cacheService, myMapper); // cacheService and myMapper are succesfully instantiated elsewhere.
        
        // Add a Foo to the database.
        var myFoo = new Foo
        {
            Id = Guid.Parse("abc-123"),
            Bars = new List<Bar> { new Bar { Id = Guid.Parse("def-456") }  }
        };
        _context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        _context.Foo.Add(myFoo);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        _context.Entry(myFoo).State = EntityState.Detached;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        // This is a DTO object that is almost the same as the Foo entity above. Same for the Bar List
        var fooDTO = new FooDTO 
        {
            Id = Guid.Parse("abc-123"),
            Bars = new List<BarDTO> { new BarDTO { Id = Guid.Parse("def-456") }  }
        }

        // act + assert 
        await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentException>(() => fooRepository.AddFooAsync(fooDTO));
    }
```

The AddFooAsync method looks like this:

```
    public async Task<FooDTO> AddFooAsync(FooDTO foo)
    {
        // use AutoMapper to turn the Foo DTO into a Foo entity. 
        var dbFoo = _mapper.Map<Foo>(foo);

        _dbContext.Foos.Add(dbFoo);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return _mapper.Map<UserDTO>(dbUser);
    }
```

This method crashes on the `_dbContext.Foos.Add(dbFoo);` line, and throws an `InvalidOperationException` instead of my expected `ArgumentException`. I get the following text:

> The instance of entity type 'Bar' cannot be tracked because another
> instance with the key value '{Id: def-456 }' is already being
> tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity
> instance with a given key value is attached

My best guess is that the Bar object is also being tracked by EF, which is giving me issues when doing a double insert. What is the best way to go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detach everything, if it is suitable for you:

```
    foreach (var e in _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        e.State = EntityState.Detached;
    }
```

Comment: That was it, I did not realize I could access my Bar class this way.